# Apache Kafka: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0

Tags: apache-kafka

I sent a single message to my Kafka by using the following code:

```
 def getHealthSink(kafkaHosts: String, zkHosts: String) = {
    val kafkaHealth: Subscriber[String] = kafka.publish(ProducerProperties(
      brokerList = kafkaHosts,
      topic = "health_check",
      encoder = new StringEncoder()
    ))
    Sink.fromSubscriber(kafkaHealth).runWith(Source.single("test"))
  }
  val kafkaHealth = getHealthSink(kafkaHosts, zkHosts)
```

and I got the following error message:

> ERROR kafka.utils.Utils$ fetching topic metadata for topics
>   [Set(health_check)] from broker
>   [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:****,port:9092)] failed
>   kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics
>   [Set(health_check)] from broker
>   [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:****,port:9092)] failed

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is incredibly unclear, but basically "Fetching topic metadata" is the first thing the producer does, which means this is where it is first establishing a connection to Kafka.

There's a good chance that either the broker you are trying to connect to is down, or there is another connectivity issue (ports, firewalls, dns, etc).

In unrelated news: You seem to be using the old and deprecated Scala producer. We recommend moving to the new Java producer (org.apache.kafka.clients.KafkaProducer)

Comment: Thanks. It IS a matter of connectivity from VM machine. As for Kafka, I see a lot of theoretical matertial on the Internet. Still, there are not enough code examples or tutorials about how to write code that communicate with a server managed by Kafka. Can you give some good links that can supply good guidance for this purpose?